# Error 502 bad gateway nginx https

Tags: nginx, https

I have a server with applications in different ports, I call them microservices, the main app is in 3000 and calls static in 3001. I configure a certificate for https and when I configure it I get error 502. I have a file xxxxx.conf for the main one and a xxxx-statics.conf file for statics. The files are like this.

```
    server {
  listen 80;
  server_name pos.xxx.co;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;

  }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name pos.xxx.co;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx/ssl-bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx/cert.xxx.co.key;


        location / {
                proxy_set_header        HOST $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_http_version      1.1;

                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                }


ssl on;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        }
```

and mi file xxx-statics.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name statics.xxxx.co;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:3001;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name statics.xxx.co;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/xxxx/ssl-bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/xxxx/cert.xxxx.co.key;


        location / {

                proxy_set_header        HOST $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
                proxy_redirect off;
                }



ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use "proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000$request_uri;"

Also in the http block the announcement of the "location /" is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks but the problem change, now the error is err_insecure_response

Comment: What type of SSL certificate do you use? Self-signed? In the config I do not see the description of the certificate